# How can i add contact info to iphone app

Tags: iphone

I have developed an iphone app. How can i add my developer email to the app? So that users can contact me? I dont see any option like android market where you can add your contact email so that if any users have questions they can contact you directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways.  Probably the easiest is to create a simple html file that you include in your bundle.  Then open a UIWebView and open the (local) html file.  On the html file, use a mailto: url.